# Set Daemon Of Python Thread In Class To True

Tags: python, multithreading, daemon

I'm coding a Texteditor class:

```
from threading import *


class Editor(Thread):
      {python code}

if __name__ == "__main__":
      editor = Editor()
      editor.start()
```

I want this editor Thread to run as daemon. How can I do this?
I've tried:

```
editor = Editor(daemon=True)

editor.daemon = True

self.daemon = True
```

Greetings,
Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the below

```
from threading import *


class Editor(Thread):
    def __init__(self, is_daemon: bool):
        super(Editor, self).__init__(daemon=is_daemon)

    def run(self):
        print('in run')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    editor = Editor(True)
    print(editor.daemon)
    editor.start()
```